# bashscript for file search and replace!

Tags: bash, scripting

Hey I try to write a littel bash script. This should copy a dir and all files in it. Then it should search each file and dir in this copied dir for a String (e.g @ForTestingOnly) and then this save the line number. Then it should go on and count each { and } as soon as the number is equals it should save againg the line number. => it should delete all the lines between this 2 numbers.
I'm trying to make a script which searchs for all this annotations and then delete the method which is directly after this ano.
Thx for help...

so far I have:

```
echo "please enter dir"
read dir
newdir="$dir""_final"
cp -r $dir $newdir 
cd $newdir

grep -lr -E '@ForTestingOnly' * | xargs sed -i 's/@ForTestingOnly//g'
```

now with grep I can search and replace the @ForTestingOnly anot. but I like to delete this and the following method...

Comment: you should probably explicitly mention why you tagged this question with "java" tag, I can only suspect that @ForTestingOnly is a Java annotation...

Comment: Care to post what you have so far?

Comment: It would be pretty easy to do this *almost* correctly as you describe it, but watch out for things like "}" characters inside comments or string literals....

Comment: I don't know how I can search for a word and save the line and then search on searching for { and } and then delete all the lines between...

Comment: You can always use your favorite programming language to code up a solution for a single file, then use the find command to apply your program recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try. It's oblivious to braces in comments and literals, though, as **David Gelhar** warned. It only finds and deletes the first occurrence of the "@ForTestingOnly" block (under the assumption that there will only be one anyway).

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -maxdepth 1 | while read -r file
do
    open=0 close=0
    # start=$(sed -n '/@ForTestingOnly/{=;q}' "$file")
    while read -r line
    do
        case $line in
            *{*) (( open++ )) ;;
            *}*) (( close++ ));;
             '') : ;;    # skip blank lines
              *) # these lines contain the line number that the sed "=" command printed
                 if (( open == close ))
                 then 
                     break
                 fi
                 ;;
        esac
             # split braces onto separate lines dropping all other chars
             # print the line number once per line that contains either { or }
    # done < <(sed -n "$start,$ { /[{}]/ s/\([{}]\)/\1\n/g;ta;b;:a;p;=}" "$file")
    done < <(sed -n "/@ForTestingOnly/,$ { /[{}]/ s/\([{}]\)/\1\n/g;ta;b;:a;p;=}" "$file")
    end=$line
    # sed -i "${start},${end}d" "$file"
    sed -i "/@ForTestingOnly/,${end}d" "$file"
done
```

**Edit:** Removed one call to `sed` (by commenting out and replacing a few lines).

**Edit 2:**

Here's a breakdown of the main `sed` line:

```
sed -n "/@ForTestingOnly/,$ { /[{}]/ s/\([{}]\)/\1\n/g;ta;b;:a;p;=}" "$file"
```

- `-n` - only print lines when explicitly requested
- `/@ForTestingOnly/,$` - from the line containing "@ForTestingOnly" to the end of the file
- `s/ ... / ... /g` perform a global (per-line) substitution
- `\( ... \)` - capture
- `[{}]` - the characters that appear in the list bewteen the square brackets
- `\1\n` - substitute what was captured plus a newline
- `ta` - if a substitution was made, branch to label "a"
- `b` - branch (no label means "to the end and begin the per-line cycle again for the next line) - this branch functions as an "else" for the `ta`, I could have used `T` instead of `ta;b;:a`, but some versions of `sed` don't support `T`
- `:a` - label "a"
- `p` - print the line (actually, print the pattern buffer which now consists of possibly multiple lines with a "{" or "}" on each one)
- `=` - print the current line number of the input file

The second `sed` command simply says to delete the lines starting at the one that has the target string and ending at the line found by the `while` loop.

The `sed` command at the top which I commented out says to find the target string and print the line number it's on and quit. That line isn't necessary since the main `sed` command is taking care of starting in the right place.

The inner `while`loop looks at the output of the main `sed` command and increments counters for each brace. When the counts match it stops.

The outer `while` loop steps through all the files in the current directory.

Comment: okey but now I like to do this for all files in the given dir. and sed hast some unknown command: ',' don't know why...

Comment: The `find` will feed each file to the process. I don't know why the comma isn't working. What version of `sed` are you using and what OS and version? I've edited the script because I noticed a slight improvement I could make.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 I'm trying the script later ony very nice work thx a lot now it would be nice to understand what each line in the script does ^^ *{* and so on are clear but the sed comands i don't get^^ cheer s

Comment: @D3orn: Running on Ubuntu 9.04 with GNU sed 4.2.1 and Bash 4.0.33(1)-release, I don't get that error. It probably means the variable "end" isn't getting set, for some reason, but I can't see any reason why not.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the bugs in the old version. The new versions has two scripts: an awk script and a bash driver.

The driver is:

```
#!/bin/bash

AWK_SCRIPT=ann.awk

for i in $(find . -type f -print); do
    while [ 1 ]; do
        cmd=$(awk -f $AWK_SCRIPT $i)
        if [ -z "$cmd" ]; then
            break
        else
            eval $cmd
        fi
    done
done
```

the new awk script is:

```
BEGIN {
# line number where we will start deleting
start = 0;
}

{
        # check current line for the annotation
        # we're looking for
        if($0 ~ /@ForTestingOnly/) {
                start = NR;
                found_first_open_brace = 0;
                num_open = 0;
                num_close = 0;
        }

        if(start != 0) {
                if(num_open == num_close && found_first_open_brace == 1) {
                        print "sed -i \'\' -e '" start "," NR " d' " ARGV[1];
                        start = 0;
                        exit;
                }
                for(i = 1; i <= length($0); i++) {
                        c = substr($0, i, 1);
                        if(c == "{") {
                                found_first_open_brace = 1;
                                num_open++;
                        }
                        if(c == "}") {
                                num_close++;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Set the path to the awk script in the driver then run the driver in the root dir.

Comment: Replace backquotes with `$()`. [Here's why.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: ty,

if your still having trouble with the find command try

$ find . -type f -print

Comment: I just found a bug in that program. It won't work if a file contains more than one annotation to be deleted. This is because once sed deletes the first annotation, the line #s of the second will change invalidating the next sed command. You will have to change the program to only produce one sed command per file, then rerun the whole thing until the awk scrip produces no output.